# Three stubborn siblings

Tags: riddle, mathematics, word

> 2560147913
>
> Three stubborn siblings,
>   of which only one is whole,
>   making history is their goal.

What word am I looking for?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer is

> EPIC.

Because the number is

> the product of three important mathematical/physical constants: $e$, $\pi$, and $c$.

Confession:

> [I Googled it.](http://brutalhonesttruths.tumblr.com/post/26583974753/i-have-moments-so-bear-with-me)

Comment: That's correct. (ROT13: Gbb onq gung ahzore jnf nyernql ba tbbtyr, vg znqr zl evqqyr gbb rnfl. V jvyy purpx orggre arkg gvzr :-))